# Plane stress and incompressibility

Tags: continuum-mechanics

The relation between bulk modulus ($K$) and Young's modulus ($E_Y$) and Poisson's ratio ($\nu$) is given by:

\begin{equation}
    K = 
    \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \frac{E_Y}{3(1-2\nu)} & \mbox{for 3D} \\[10pt]
        \frac{E_Y}{2(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)} & \mbox{for 2D plane strain} \\[10pt]
        \frac{E_Y}{2(1-\nu)} & \mbox{for 2D plane stress}
    \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation}

Under incompressibility, the Poisson's ratio is $\nu$ = 1/2, so the bulk modulus would be:

\begin{equation}
    K = 
    \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \infty & \mbox{for 3D} \\[10pt]
        \infty & \mbox{for 2D plane strain} \\[10pt]
        E_Y & \mbox{for 2D plane stress}
    \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation}

The 2D plane strain assumption recovers the value of 3D, but the 2D plane stress does not. So, my question is: is it correct to say that plane stress assumption does not model incompressibility?

---

PS: my original question has an error in equations that led to an incorrect interpretation of physical behavior. The correct equation for 2D plane stress is:

\begin{equation}
    K = 
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \frac{E_Y}{2(1-2\nu)} & \mbox{for 2D plane stress}
    \end{array}
\end{equation}

With this correction $K$ = $\infty$ for 2D plane stress too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct. An incompressible material can not change its total volume, but it can change its shape.

If a compressive plane stress is applied, the material gets thinner in the $z$ direction but expands in $x$ and $y$ directions (as given by Poisson's ratio) so that its volume remains constant.

Under plane *strain*, the expansion in $x$ and $y$ is prevented by definition of what plane strain means. Therefore its thickness can't change, and the material is not only incompressible *but also perfectly rigid.*

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this doubt. After thinking about your answer I went back to the equations and I was able to find the error.