# Would anyone be able to provide a reference for the equations concerning plane strain and incompressibility?

Tags: resource-recommendations, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, solid-mechanics

I've been trying really hard to find a textbook or research paper that mentions the equations I mentioned in my question. Sadly, I haven't had any luck so far. Would it be possible for someone to kindly help me out by providing a reference to these equations?

[Equations presented in this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/499721/plane-stress-and-incompressibility)

\begin{equation}
    K = 
    \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \frac{E_Y}{3(1-2\nu)} & \mbox{for 3D} \\[10pt]
        \frac{E_Y}{2(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)} & \mbox{for 2D plane strain} \\[10pt]
        \frac{E_Y}{2(1-\nu)} & \mbox{for 2D plane stress}
    \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation}

Comment: Google Hooke's law.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's straightforward enough to derive these.

The (isothermal) bulk modulus $K$ is defined as $K\equiv-V\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_T$ (often written simply as $K\equiv-V\frac{dP}{dV}$ or $K\equiv-V\frac{\Delta P}{\Delta V}$, with the isothermal condition implicitly assumed).

Consider $\frac{\Delta V}{V}=(1+\varepsilon_{11})(1+\varepsilon_{22})(1+\varepsilon_{33})-1$ for small strains; by a Taylor series expansion, this is approximately $\varepsilon_{11}+\varepsilon_{22}+\varepsilon_{33}$.

For a pressure applied to a stress-free state, we have $\Delta P=P$.

[Generalized Hooke's Law for isotropic materials](http://john.maloney.org/Structural/generalized%20Hooke%27s%20Law.htm) is

$$\varepsilon_{ij}=\frac{1+\nu}{E}\sigma_{ij}-\frac{\nu}{E}\sigma_{kk}\delta_{ij};$$

$$\sigma_{ij}=\frac{E}{1+\nu}\varepsilon_{ij}+\frac{\nu E}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}\varepsilon_{kk}\delta_{ij},$$

with Poisson's ratio $\nu$, Young's modulus $E$, and [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) $\delta_{ij}$.

In addition, we have $\sigma_{11}=\sigma_{22}=\sigma_{33}=-P$ for the equitriaxial case, $\sigma_{11}=\sigma_{22}$ and $\varepsilon_{33}=0$ for the equibiaxial 2D plane strain case, and $\sigma_{11}=\sigma_{22}$ and $\sigma_{33}=0$ for the equibiaxial 2D plane stress case.

From this, $\varepsilon_{11}+\varepsilon_{22}+\varepsilon_{33}$ is determined to be $\frac{3(1-2\nu)}{E}(-P)$ for the 3D case (use the first Hooke's law equation), $\frac{2(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}{E}\sigma_{11}$ for the 2D plane strain case (use the second Hooke's law equation), and $\frac{2(1-\nu)}{E}\sigma_{11}$ for the 2D plane stress case (use the first Hooke's law equation).

Thus, $K=\frac{E}{3(1-2\nu)}$ for the 3D case, $K=\frac{E}{2(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}$ for the 2D plane strain case, and $K=\frac{E}{2(1-\nu)}$ for the 2D plane stress case. For the last two, the relevant "pressure" is taken as $-\sigma_{11}$. These match the equations you ask about, QED.